# PHP - Required File Cannot Read Any Variables

Tags: php

My PHP is set up in a way where each page runs as followed:

```
require('config.php'); //variables, db, etc
$content = "all page output";
require('design.php');
```

However - any time a page called with `require()` from `design.php` it cannot read any variables. `$vars`, `get`, `post`, globals, constants, etc. All I can seem to get it to run are session variables.
It should be noted that the variables load fine if I cut/paste the code from the `require()` files straight to `design.php`.

From my understanding `include()`/`require()` acted as if the code was just cut and pasted in the desired spot. However, this is giving me a world of issues.

***Code breakdown***

*config.php*

```
$systemProductURL = 'http://test.com/cart/';
```

> $systemProductURL is the variable which isn't being passed along the entire way. I can echo it out fine from config.php.

---

*design.php*

```
include $systemProductURL . 'inc/components/defaultMainMenu/display.php';
```

> This page is entirely design, it does no calculations or change variables in anyway. It uses $systemProductURL to call display.php. $systemProductURL works fine here in design.php **but is unreadable in display.php**. I know the include() is reaching the desired file as I can echo out plain text from display.php just fine.

---

*display.php*

```
<? echo $systemProductURL; ?>
```

> This is where the problem is. For the life of me I cannot get display.php to echo $systemProductURL. This is the entire page.

---

*The page that the user visits. I'll use my homepage, index.php as example*

```
require 'inc/config.php';
$pageContent .= "
 <div class='pageContentBody' style='width: 100%'>
  content
 </div>";
require 'inc/design.php';
```

> This page and any other page that is visited by the user can use $systemProductURL perfectly.

Comment: Please show us the content of `config.php` and `design.php` (The minimum necessary to demonstrate the issue)

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("**why isn't this code working?**") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Sorry, I've added more information. Please check under code breakdown.

Comment: I've discovered that if I don't use absolute pathing to call display.php I can use the variables in config.php. Is there anyway to use an absolute path and still use the variables?